# How to rsync to different directory?

Tags: rsync

Here is what I want to achieve:

Run Rsync to compare two directories recursively like this:

```
rsync -r /source /target
```

but don't actually rsync between the directories. I want the resulting differences to be rsyncd/copied to another 3. directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

`--compare-dest` is your friend here:

```
rsync -rvn --compare-dest /target/ /source/ /extra_target/
```

(Remove -v and -n after confirming it works for you)

Here's a shell session showing it:

```
dennis@lightning:~$ cd /tmp
dennis@lightning:/tmp$ mkdir rs1
dennis@lightning:/tmp$ touch rs1/f1
dennis@lightning:/tmp$ rsync -av rs1/ rs2/
sending incremental file list
created directory rs2
./
f1

sent 96 bytes  received 34 bytes  260.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
dennis@lightning:/tmp$ touch rs1/f2
dennis@lightning:/tmp$ rsync -avn rs1/ rs2/
sending incremental file list
./
f2

sent 71 bytes  received 18 bytes  178.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
dennis@lightning:/tmp$ rsync -avn rs1/ rs3/
sending incremental file list
created directory rs3
./
f1
f2

sent 49 bytes  received 15 bytes  128.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
dennis@lightning:/tmp$ rsync -rnv --compare-dest /tmp/rs2/ rs1/ rs3/
sending incremental file list
created directory rs3
f2

sent 49 bytes  received 15 bytes  128.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```